# Translate group definition into geometry system

Tags: group-theory, analytic-geometry

I need to reword the definition of group (the four axioms: closure, associativity, identity and invertibility) to be lines and points of non-Euclidean geometry (the axiom system defined as geometry). And I just can't find an analogue for points and lines :(

I.e. for example, the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ relative to the operation $+_{\pmod 4}$ could be the model for the above system, but I simply cannot understand how to "draw" it using lines and points.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I am confused. Why do you _need_ to do this?

Comment: That's part of the homework I got. The course's subject is the axiom systems expressed in non-Euclidean geometry. What I'm asking above isn't exactly the homework question though, it's a prerequisite to solve another number of questions (which are much easier, if you don't have to build the model of lines and points...)